# I have the equation $(1 − B)y_t = (1 − B)a_t$, can I conclude from this that $y_t=a_t$ for all $t$?

Tags: time-series, self-study

I have the equation $(1 − B)y_t = (1 − B)a_t$, am I able to say that this equation implies that $y_t = a_t$ for all t?

$B$ is the backward shift operator where $Bz_t = z_{t-1}$ and 
$y_t = y_{t-1} + \mu + \sigma a_t$ where $a_t$ is a sequence of independent random variable $N(0,1)$, $\sigma$ is the volatility, and $\mu$ the mean growth rate.

I know: $y_t = y_{t-1} + \mu + \sigma *a_t$

$y_t -\mu * t= y_{t-1} - \mu * (t-1) + \sigma *a_t$

where $z_t = z_{t-1} + \sigma * a_t$

so $a_t = (z_t - z_{t-1})/ \sigma$

I Guess I just don't know how to show whether or not $y_t$ and  $a_t$ are defined for the same t. I know according to time series that t is today where as t-1 was yesterday (or the past) and t+1 is the future.

Comment: This is most definitely a self-study, I am preparing for an up coming test, essentially I don't know how to use time series in order to conclude if yt=at for all t. what do you mean read its wiki?  @gung

Comment: Thank you for adding the tag; if you click the hyperlinked [wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info), you will be taken to a page explaining our policies. Please tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Comment: Are you sure the equations are correct? I mean, if $(1-B) y_t = (1-B) a_t$ then $y_t = y_{t-1} + a_t - a_{t-1}$. From now on it seems that there is some information missing. How do you get from the equation above to $y_t = y_{t-1} + \mu + \sigma * a_t$? Is this given? And how $\mu$ turns into $\mu * t$?

Comment: yt=yt−1+μ+σ∗at is given. to get u*t i just added and subtracted u*t from the yt formula

Comment: What the equation $(1-B)y_t=(1-B)a_t$ says is that the increments in $y_t$ equal the increments in $a_t$. Does that sound sufficient for $y_t\equiv a_t$?

Comment: @RichardHardy well the way I see it is that i need to show that (1-B)^(-1) exists for yt=at...

Comment: i know (1-B)yt=(1-B)at so in order for it to be implied that yt=at i need to show that (1-B)(1-B)^(-1)yt=at where the inverse (1-B)^(-1) has to exist in order to imply that yt=at. @RichardHardy

Comment: You are trying to prove something that might or might not be true. What about two sequences: $y=(1,2,3)$ and $a=(11,12,13)$? Isn't it true that $(1-B)y_t=(1-B)a_t$?

Comment: well no clearly that won't be true

Answer (score 3):

Look at the comment by @Richard Hardy:

> What the equation $(1-B)y_t=(1-B)a_t$ says is that the increments in $y_t$ equal the increments in $a_t$. Does that sound sufficient for $y_t\equiv a_t$?

To make it more clear, make a numerical example where two series have the same increment:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8  9  10
3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
```

and the answer should be clear. An analogy with calculus is that two functions might have the same derivative without being equal.